# Read a text file line by line and search eachline another file php script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to read a file line by line and search each lines another file with php script on unıx.an write results to another file.

How can I do this?
I mean;

file1:

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5
```

file2:

```
.....
192.168.1.3
192.168.12.123
192.168.34.56
192.168.1.5
....
```

file3:

```
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5
```

I want to read file1 each lines and search each line file2.And if I have matches this search write results file3.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: sorry about that but I am not devaloper..so I dig a lot about problem but ı dıdn fınd.so thıs ıs not only one thıng my problem, just part of it, so ı have to be quick about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$file1 = file('file1', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$file2 = file('file2', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$file3Content = implode('', array_intersect($file1, $file2));
file_put_contents('file3', $file3Content);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have to ask some case about it. file1 " 192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5 "  and file2 ".....
2192.168.1.3'
'192.168.12.123' cre1
'192.168.34.56'corewe2
'192.168.1.5' core
...."  in this case how can I seach  file1 lines to file2?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you could read both files using `file()` function and they will both return as an array. Then use `array_intersect()`. Consider this example:

```
$ip1 = file('ip1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$ip2 = file('ip2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$results = array_intersect($ip1, $ip2); // intersection of two arrays
$ip3 = implode("\n", $results); // put them back together
file_put_contents('ip3.txt', $ip3); // put it inside the third file
```

`$results` should contain (based on your example) this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 192.168.1.3
    [2] => 192.168.1.5
)
```